# google analytics data is not showing up - Tracking not installed

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem with google analytics for web.

I installed the analytics as following just before the closing head tag.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


//        ga('create', 'UA-xxxx23-1', 'auto');
        ga('create', 'UA-xxxx56-2', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

It is weird because on one UA code (the one that is uncommented) no data is coming through ans the status of the tracking code is "tracker is not installed".
While the other property on another account the data is coming in correctly and the status is "Receiving data".

Any idea what this problem might be?

Comment: how long ago did you create that tracking code? takes up to 72 hours for a new one to kick in.

Comment: old versus new (universal) analytic profile?

Comment: Please check Real-Time reports to see if you see any hits. If you do, then it usually takes anywhere from 24-48 hours for data to be processed to the standard reports, during which time you can ignore the status messages.

Comment: Turns out it took some time for all settings to sync. But the weird thing was that no real time data was coming through aswell. Anyways it works now

Answer (score 18):

Turns out it was a time issue. The settings took around a day to kick in. The weird thing was that no realtime data was coming through. But now it works. If anyone has the same problem, just be patient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple tracking ID then you have to pass the name field as the fourth argument in the create command.

```
 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'myTracker');
```

And then you have to prefix the command name with the tracker name, followed by a dot.

```
ga('myTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

finally your code will look like this with double tracker

```
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto', 'clientTracker');

ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview');
```